# Problem with aggregation, column creation and connection in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame1 like below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID3"], "number": [
                   11, 1, 30, 4, 5], "number2": [55, 23, 12, 66, 78]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4",
                           "ID5"], "item": ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"]})
```

And I would like to:

1. Make aggregation, when I sum values from "number" column for each ID from "ID" column
2. Create new column "new" where will be the highest value from "number2" column for each ID from "ID" column (for instance, for ID1 the biggest val. from number2 column is 55, for ID2 66, for ID3 78)
3. Connect df1 with df2 based on "ID", nevertheless I do not want to have any NaN, so I ned to take df1 and add only matching columns so ID1, ID2 and ID3.

To be more precision below I load table wthich I need to have as a result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's do `merge` and `groupby`:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on='ID')
    .groupby(['ID','item'], as_index=False)
    .agg({'number':'sum', 'number2':'max'})
)
```

Output:

```
    ID item  number  number2
0  ID1   aa      11       55
1  ID2   bb      35       66
2  ID3   cc       5       78
```